# How to schedule send different message to different user via websocket

Tags: java, spring, websocket

different users will set different reminders in the system such that once he/she log in the system, he/she can see the the reminders at specified time.

for example, there is reminder `please handle this booking` and the remind time is `2020-07-05 10:00`, then the browser should alert this message at `2020-07-05 10:00`.

And there is a schedule task to get reminders every 30 minutes.

In order to achieve it, I intend to use websocket. I am using `struts2 and spring`.

My code looks like:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/ws/{userId}")
public class Test {
        
    private String userId;
    
    private static Map<String, Session> map = new HashMap<>();    
   
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(@PathParam("userId") String userId,Session session) throws IOException{
        
        this.userId = userId;       
        map.put(userId, session);
    }    
   
    @OnClose
    public void onClose(){

        map.remove(userId);
    }    
   
    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) throws IOException {
        ...
    }    
    
    @OnError
    public void onError(Session session, Throwable error){
        ...
    }

    public static Map<String, Session> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public static void setMap(Map<String, Session> map) {
        Test.map = map;
    }

}
```

the schedule is:

```
@EnableScheduling
@Component
public class ScheduleAction {   

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0,30 * * * ?")
    public void listReminder(){
       
        Map<String, Session> map = Test.getMap();
        
        Iterator<String> ite = map.keySet().iterator();
        
        while(ite.hasNext()) {
            
            String userId = ite.next();
            //get the reminders of this user
            map.get(userId).getAsyncRemote().sendText(allRemindersOfThisUser);
        }
    }

}
```

my questions are:

1. is the code correct? There are only two hundred users at most use this system at the same time now.
2. is the code correct if there are more users use this system concurrently?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have worked out details of how you are going to pass across the userId+Session map across two beans (which is very much doable without dobut), above approach will work for sending the notifications.

Having said that, the next challenge is scalability. There are two potential challanges that I see in the presented code/design outline.

1. The sequential processing nature can delay processing of events for users as userbase grows, it'll also be dependent on how much time consuming "***get the reminders of this user***" routine is.
2. Practically you are polling for events and as such any new event created between two polling periods wouldn't be available to user immediately.

#1 can be solved with ease with spring async with appropriate configuration of executor. Following snippet present the solution outline using @Async

```
@EnableScheduling

@Component
public class ScheduleAction {
    @Autowired
    private UserNotifier userNotifier;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0,30 * * * ?")
    public void listReminder(){
        Map<String, Session> map = Test.getMap();

        map.forEach((user, session) ->
            userNotifier.sendNotificaitonsForUser(user,session));
    }
}

/**
 * A separte bean is neccesary for spring to execute the notification
 * asynchronously using executor of it's own.
 */
@Component
public class UserNotifier {
    @Async
    public void sendNotificaitonsForUser(String user, Session session) {
        //get the reminders of this user
        session.getAsyncRemote().sendText(allRemindersOfThisUser);
    }
}
```

Further details of @Async can be found in [How To Do @Async in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async) article.

For #2, it'll demand another event based design in your core application itself. Any new event created/updated in business layer should generate an event which, by means of appropriate listener, should be evaluated and sent across to impacted user(s). [Spring Events](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events) will be a good starting point to work out this solution outline. Having said that, if your use case do not demand immediate notification of new events than polling is good enough and you do not have to work out these additional event based notifications.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: thanks for your detail answer, it's great help for me!